# Change Excel Slicer from "OR" to "AND"

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, pivot-chart

I'm trying to graph the number of people who have a certain skill set, using a slicer. The problem that I'm running into is that the slicer tool, by default, will show me ALL of the records that satisfy any of the criteria selected. So, for example, if I select "Python" and "NodeJS" as skills, it will show everyone who has one OR the other. However, I'd like to view people who have BOTH.

I've come across this article (https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/04/turning-or-slicers-into-and-slicers/), but I'm wondering if anyone has an easier solution? I've tried this and am running into issues getting it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: helper column? how many unique skill combos are you looking at?

Comment: How about adding 2 slicer with different conditional?

Answer (score 0):

My impression is this is simpler than trying to change the behavior of the slicer.

I take it from your post that you have a list of (at the very least), Person and Skill.

If you select your table then use 'Power Pivot>Add to Data Model', it will open the PowerPivot window. From there, use 'Home>Pivot Table' to create a Power Pivot on your data.

After you've done that, you can add Person to the Values area of the Pivot, then change the aggregation to 'Distinct Count':

[image]

You'll see that even if you select 2 skills that one person has, it will only count that person once. Bart, for example, is skilled in both Mocking Homer and Skateboarding:

[image]